# Attached Properties Add With Code

Tags: c#, wpf

I want attached properties to element's when i create them with C# code example set Name to TranslateTransform Class .

Is it Possible? if so, how?

thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
OwningClass.SetPropertyName(someInstance, someValue);
```

Comment: OwningClass is where (in which namespace)

Comment: `OwningClass` is that class that contains the property, in whatever namespace it's defined in.

Comment: I cant understand please write example (set name property to TranslateTransform Class) thank you.

Comment: The `x:Name` property is not an attached property; its' a special property related to XAML compilation.  There is no reason to set it in code.